# Restringir un autorizador de que se autorice asi mismo

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

¿Será que me puedan ayudar con este código?

```
 <%
                int nd=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nd"));
            
            Connection conc = null;
                PreparedStatement pstc = null;
                ResultSet rsc = null;

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conc = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");
                    pstc = conc.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM rhcontino WHERE nd='" + nd + "' and tipodeusuario='2'");
                    rsc = pstc.executeQuery();

                    while (rsc.next()) {
                        
                    
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            Connection con1 = null;
            PreparedStatement pst1 = null;
            ResultSet rs1 = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");
                con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");

                pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM rhcopia");
                pst1 = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM rhcopia");
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();

                String bsc = request.getParameter("buscare");
        %>
        <h1 align="center">Hello World! <%=rsc.getString(2)%></h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <!--<input type="text" name="buscare" />-->
            <select name="buscare">
                <option><%=bsc%></option>
                <%
                    while (rs1.next()) {
                %>
                <option><%=rs1.getString(2)%></option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
        </form>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <%
            if (bsc != null) {
                pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from rhcopia where nombrejefe='" + bsc + "'");
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
            }
        
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (bsc == null) {
            %>
            <input type="text" />
            <%
            } else if(bsc == rs.getString(1)){
    %>
    <div>GI</div>

<%
    } else {
                %>
                <input type="text" name="nombrejefe" style="display: none" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" />
                <input type="text" name="puestojefe" value="<%=rs.getString(3)%>" />
                <input type="text" name="correojefe" value="<%=rs.getString(4)%>" />
                <%
                    }                }
                %>
                <input type="submit" name="gtn" value="Subir dato" />
            </form>
            <%
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){}
            %>
```

Miren, estoy simulando que un autorizador entró a su cuenta de sesión, ¿ok? Bueno, intento que sus datos en su cuenta no aparezcan en la caja de texto para que no se autroice nada asi mismo, pero resulta que por más que lo intento, poner que si el resultado seleccionado es igual al nombre del usuario de la cuenta que no me aparezca mas que un mensaje en `<div>`, siempre me rebota los datos que por cierto provienen de una tabla aparte, no de la tabla de usuarios si no de una aparte de autorizadores, le puse rhcopia creo, pero el detalle es que lo que estoy haciendo no está funcionando, si alguien tiene alguna idea seria de mucho agradecer que lo compartiera por favor, muchas gracias, buen dia

Answer (score 0):

A ver si entiendo, corregime si me equivoco. Vos queres hacer que un usuario entre en una aplicacion y que en una lista donde estan los otros usuarios, el no aparezca?. Es algo asi?....
Te digo como lo haria yo, por ahi te sirve como idea, suponiendo que tu app tiene dos pantallas una de login y la otra donde esta la lista de usuarios. Yo le pasaria un bean con el usuario logueado a la segunda pantalla y en la segunda hago un select a los usuarios que no son los usuarios del bean.
Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).